# How to use a single date table for two date fields?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Power BI Desktop to explore some data. I have a table called "Reports" which contains a list of reports that need to be filed. There are two date fields, "Due Date" and "Date Completed".

I have a single date table, Dates. It has been marked as my date table in Power Bi.

My goal is produce a matrix where each row is a month in the due date and each column is a month in the date completed. However, I can't figure out how to get Power BI to use the dates table for both of my date fields. I can join it in the relationships pane - but it looks like I can have only a single active relationship at a time.  I've also tried the "Get Data" feature to add the date table multiple times, but it will only add once.

How can I use my date table for more than one date field at a given time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two relationships to the dates table-- one is Active, one is Inactive.  All measures will use the Active relationship, and to calculate data in the reports using the inactive relationship you create DAX Measures using the `USERELATIONSHIP()` function.

Here is a couple resources:

- https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/userelationship-in-calculated-columns/
- https://carldesouza.com/power-bi-dax-userelationship-multiple-dates/